# PHP export to CSV file has first two rows empty

Tags: php

I have the below data in an array and want to write to CSV file. Everything is working except i see first two empty lines in the .csv file

Any help is appreciated... Thanks again!!!!

Output in CSV file looks like 
    empty Line1
    empty Line2
    ip address ip state description hostmane mac owner device notes
    data......

Array data:

```
Array (
[0] =>Array ( [ip address] => 1.3.2.1 [ip state] => Active [description] => [hostname] => [mac] => [owner] => [device] => [note] => ) 
[1] =>Array ( [ip address] => 1.3.2.2 [ip state] => Reserved [description] => [hostname] => linux [mac] => [owner] => test [device] => Linux Server [note] => Linux123 )
[2] => Array ( [ip address] => 1.3.2.3 [ip state] => Active [description] => [hostname] => [mac] => [owner] => [device] => [note] => )
[3] => Array ( [ip address] => 1.3.2.4 [ip state] => Active [description] => [hostname] => [mac] => [owner] => [device] => [note] => )
)
```

PHP Function i am using to write to CSV file is:

```
switch("export-to-csv")
{   
    case "export-to-csv" :
        // Submission from
        $filename = $_GET["exformat"] . ".csv";
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        header("Expires: 0");
        ExportCSVFile($data);
        //$_GET["exformat"] = '';
        exit();
    default :
        die("Unknown action : ".$_POST["action"]);
        break;
}

function ExportCSVFile($records) {
    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream 
    #print_r ($records); return;
    $fh = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
    $heading = false;
    if(!empty($records)) {
        foreach($records as $row) {            
            if(!$heading)  {
              // output the column headings
              fputcsv($fh, array_keys($row));
              $heading = true;
            }
        // loop over the rows, outputting them
         fputcsv($fh, array_values($row));              
      }       

    }
}
```

Comment: You could add an else condition after `if(!$heading)` to check for an empty string ('') as well.  I would recommend trimming the string to catch for entries that are only spaces.

Comment: Thanks devlin for your quick reply.
I tried using this line before if(!$heading)

$row = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $row)); but did not helped.

Comment: Anyone one know how i can avoid first two empty lines under .csv file...

Comment: Try adding ob_clean(); before fputcsv. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please any of the files like index.php of the framework or any other file having empty lines in the beginning, this can cause empty lines in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your other files which are included before the function call and which have print space or etc. You can check that using notepad open the exported csv file in notepad you can see if there is space or not your php code is working perfect there is no any issue with that. I have tested with bellow array its working fine.

```
$data = array(
    '0' => array('ip address' => '1.3.2.1', 'ip state' => 'Active'),
    '1' => array('ip address' => '1.3.2.2', 'ip state' => 'Reserved'),
    '2' => array('ip address' => '1.3.2.3', 'ip state' => 'Active'),
    '3' => array('ip address' => '1.3.2.4', 'ip state' => 'Active')
);

switch ("export-to-csv")
{
    case "export-to-csv" :
        $filename = "1.csv";
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        header("Expires: 0");
        ExportCSVFile($data);
        exit();
    default :
        die("Unknown action : " . $_POST["action"]);
        break;
}

function ExportCSVFile($records)
{
    $fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $heading = false;
    if (!empty($records))
    {
        foreach ($records as $row)
        {
            if (!$heading)
            {
                fputcsv($fh, array_keys($row));
                $heading = true;
            }
            fputcsv($fh, array_values($row));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ravneet and Mitul for your reply.

 That is a good pointer for me to check my index.php.
One quick question in the meantime, if the array which i am writing to CSV file does not have any spaces, then why fputcsv function writes empty space?

 Also i checked the output in notepad and that also shows me two new empty lines.

 i also tried to check for empty lines in a array before writing to CSV file, that also does not work. 

 Any idea???

Comment: When you download any file using the php code then if there is extra space or content before and after that then it will automatically add content in the output file